# How can I look for overlapped and duplicated IPs in a 10 thousand rows dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which has as the following columns:

```
Site IP     Site Name   Instance    Interface Name  Network Add     Interface IP
20.X.X.1    ROUTER1     VPRN1       interface1      20.49.128.0/17  20.49.208.129   
20.X.X.2    ROUTER2     VPRN1       interface2      20.84.34.0/24   20.84.34.3
20.X.X.3    ROUTER3     VPRN1       interface3      20.84.34.0/24   20.84.34.3
20.X.X.4    ROUTER4     VPRN1       interface4      20.85.51.0/23   20.85.51.1
20.X.X.5    ROUTER5     VPRN1       interface5      20.85.52.0/24   20.85.52.1
```

And i need to create a new column called "Status", then compare if the IP Addresses are in a overlapped subnet or duplicated like this:

```
Site IP     Site Name   Instance    Interface Name  Network Add     Interface IP        Status
20.X.X.1    ROUTER1     VPRN1       interface1      20.49.128.0/17  20.49.208.129       OK
20.X.X.2    ROUTER2     VPRN1       interface2      20.84.34.0/24   20.84.34.3          Duplicated
20.X.X.3    ROUTER3     VPRN1       interface3      20.84.34.0/24   20.84.34.3          Duplicated
20.X.X.4    ROUTER4     VPRN1       interface4      20.85.51.0/23   20.85.51.1          Overlapped
20.X.X.5    ROUTER5     VPRN1       interface5      20.85.52.0/24   20.85.52.1          Overlapped
```

I hope you can help me.
thanks a lot.
Juan Pablo.

Comment: not the same. the output table has a new column called status

Answer (score 0):

You can do np.select:

```
df['Status'] = np.select( (df['Network Address'].duplicated(keep=False), 
                           df['Interface IP'].duplicated(keep=False)),
                          ('Duplicated', ‘Overlapped'), 'OK')
```

Comment: Quang, thaks for your reply, but the result is not the expected.There are some identified overlapped cases, that indicates OK. And there are not duplicated cases that are shown "duplicated"